# On update triggering in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I create 2 tables employees and customers.The employees table code is here:

```
create table employees(
employeeNumber     number not null,
lastName           varchar2(30) not null,
firstName          varchar2(30) not null,
email              varchar2(50) not null,
officeCode         varchar2(10) not null,
assignTo           number default null,
jobTitle           varchar2(100) not null,
primary key (employeeNumber),
foreign key (officeCode) references offices(officeCode),
foreign key (assignTo)  references  employees(employeeNumber)
);
```

here assignTo is a foreign key of his own table employees and employeeNumber is auto increment.Some insertion sample is here:

```
 insert into employees (lastName,firstName,email,officeCode,jobTitle)
 values ('hasan','rumy','md.rejaulhasanrumy@gmail.com','123','manager');
 insert into employees (lastName,firstName,email,officeCode,assignTo,jobTitle)
 values ('hasan','rakib','kalorakib@gmail.com','123', 1 ,'assistant manager');
```

The customer table code is here:

```
create table customers (
customerNumber    number not null,
customerName      varchar2(50) not null,
phone             varchar2(20) not null,
address           varchar2(70) not null,
city              varchar2(50) not null,
postalCode        varchar2(15) not null,
country           varchar2(40) not null,
salesRepEmployeeNumber  number default null,
primary key(customerNumber),
foreign key (salesRepEmployeeNumber) references employees (employeeNumber) 
);
```

customerNumber is auto increment.some sample insertion is here:

```
insert into customers
(customerName,phone,address,city,postalCode,country,salesRepEmployeeNumber)
values ('roxy','017456','holy park','kolia','Z143','something',1);
```

Now I create a trigger which execute before update employeeNumber column of employees table for on update cascade and the code is here:

```
create or replace trigger employees_update 
before update of employeeNumber on employees 
for each row
begin
update employees 
set 
assignTo = :new.employeeNumber
where assignTo = :old.employeeNumber;
update customers set
salesRepEmployeeNumber = :new.employeeNumber
where salesRepEmployeeNumber = :old.employeeNumber;
end;
/
```

above all is right in oracle but the problem is when I update employees table.The update code is here:

```
update employees set employeeNumber = 134 where employeeNumber = 1;
```

the problem is here:

```
    ORA-04091: table RUMY.EMPLOYEES is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "RUMY.EMPLOYEES_UPDATE", line 2
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'RUMY.EMPLOYEES_UPDATE'

1. update employees set employeeNumber = 134 where employeeNumber = 1;
```

As far I know it's a system problem so where I make mistake?Can not I make foreign key assignTo of employees table?Also notice that same thing work properly in mysql.Advance thanks for answering this long question.

Comment: Run this `SHOW ERRORS TRIGGER employees_update` for more details

Comment: the query 'show errors trigger employees_update' occurs an error which is :  "invalid SQL statement" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have discovered, you cannot select from the same table that a row-level trigger is defined against; it causes a table mutating exception.

Then - assuming at least Oracle 11, this will need to be split into individual triggers in earlier versions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER employees_update
  FOR UPDATE ON employees
  COMPOUND TRIGGER

  TYPE employeeNumberRec IS RECORD
    (oldEmployeeNumber employees.employeeNumber%TYPE
    ,newEmployeeNumber employees.employeeNumber%TYPE);
  TYPE employeeNumbersTbl IS TABLE OF employeeNumberRec;
  g_employeeNumbers employeeNumbersTbl;

BEFORE STATEMENT 
IS
BEGIN
  -- Reset the internal employees table
  g_employeeNumbers := employeeNumbersTbl();
END BEFORE STATEMENT; 

AFTER EACH ROW
IS
BEGIN
  -- Store the updated employees
  IF :new.employeeNumber  <> :old.employeeNumber THEN           
    g_employeeNumbers.EXTEND;
    g_employeeNumbers(g_employeeNumbers.LAST).oldEmployeeNumber := :old.employeeNumber;
    g_employeeNumbers(g_employeeNumbers.LAST).newEmployeeNumber := :new.employeeNumber;
  END IF;
END AFTER EACH ROW;

AFTER STATEMENT
IS
BEGIN
  -- Now update the child tables
  FORALL l_index IN 1..g_employeeNumbers.COUNT
    UPDATE employees 
    SET assignTo = g_employeeNumbers(l_index).newEmployeeNumber
    WHERE assignTo = g_employeeNumbers(l_index).oldEmployeeNumber;
  FORALL l_index IN 1..g_employeeNumbers.COUNT
    UPDATE customers
    SET salesRepEmployeeNumber = g_employeeNumbers(l_index).newEmployeeNumber
    WHERE salesRepEmployeeNumber = g_employeeNumbers(l_index).oldEmployeeNumber;
END AFTER STATEMENT;

END;
```

**EDIT**

In addition you will need to make the foreign key constraints that reference this table deferred e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE employees
  (employeeNumber NUMBER       NOT NULL
  ,lastName       VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
  ,firstName      VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL
  ,email          VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
  ,officeCode     VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL
  ,assignTo       NUMBER DEFAULT NULL
  ,jobTitle       VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY (employeeNumber)
  ,FOREIGN KEY (officeCode)
     REFERENCES offices (officeCode)
  ,FOREIGN KEY (assignTo)
     REFERENCES employees (employeeNumber)
     DEFERRABLE
     INITIALLY DEFERRED
  )
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE customers
  (customerNumber         NUMBER       NOT NULL
  ,customerName           VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
  ,phone                  VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
  ,address                VARCHAR2(70) NOT NULL
  ,city                   VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
  ,postalCode             VARCHAR2(15) NOT NULL
  ,country                VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL
  ,salesRepEmployeeNumber NUMBER DEFAULT NULL
  ,PRIMARY KEY (customerNumber)
  ,FOREIGN KEY (salesRepEmployeeNumber)
     REFERENCES employees (employeeNumber)
     DEFERRABLE
     INITIALLY DEFERRED
  )
```

Note: if the constraint is violated this will cause an error at `COMMIT` not after an individual DML statement.

Comment: still show this problem @DrabJay " integrity constraint (RUMY.SYS_C0027919825) violated - child record found " and also thanks for helping me to know some new feature.

Comment: @RumyHasan You will need to make the foreign key constraints referencing employees.employeeNumber `DEFERRABLE`; and `DEFFERED` for this transaction, either thorough the table statement or via an `ALTER SESSION` statement.

Comment: I don't understand.so can you give me some example or any link which can help me?Notice that the above commented problem is happen when I want to update.

Answer (score -1):

You can re-write the above trigger in following ways to avoid the issues:

```
create or replace trigger employees_update 
before update of employeeNumber on employees 
for each row
begin
emp_upd_trg_proc(:new.employeeNumber,:old.employeeNumber);
update customers set
salesRepEmployeeNumber = :new.employeeNumber
where salesRepEmployeeNumber = :old.employeeNumber;
end;
/

create or replace procedure emp_upd_trg_proc
(new number, old number)
is
pragma autonomous_transaction;
begin
update employees 
set 
assignTo = new
where assignTo = old;
commit;
end;
```

/

Comment: It is never appropriate to use an autonomous transaction to work around a mutating trigger error.  First off, it breaks transactional integrity-- the original update may be rolled back but the autonomous transaction cannot be, so you may be left in an invalid state.  The autonomous transaction cannot see data changes made but not committed by the triggering transaction so your procedure may generate a foreign key exception if it is trying to point the `assignTo` to a row that was inserted as part of the parent transaction.